# How to Set Default Action with Windows EXE (HTML Links)

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, hyperlink, exe

So I have a local web server run on Chrome that tries to open an EXE file through a link (`<a>`). When I run it, it tries to download the file rather than run it. Is there a way I can set the default action to run when an EXE is opened in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  With most files you can click the arrow next to the download and say "always open files of this type", but Chrome is smart enough to prevent you from doing this for executables.  This is a very dangerous thing to do.

Comment: I can see why that would be dangerous, even with local files. Imagine what would happen if some sort of malware did stuff with that... :)